# Javascript promise for loop chain order fail

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

I try test javascript promise loop chain, but I fail, the promise loop not order I wish, my sample like this(1 set timeout, 3 promise function):

```
//timeout
timeout = function (fn, pkg) {
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        fn(pkg);
        clearTimeout(t);
    }, 1000);
};
//Promise function
p01 = function (check) {
    return new Promise(function (RS, RJ) {
        var echo = 'Run P01';
        timeout(RS, echo);
    });
};
p02 = function (check) {
    return new Promise(function (RS, RJ) {
        var echo = 'Run P02';
        timeout(RS, echo);
    });
};
p03 = function (check) {
    return new Promise(function (RS, RJ) {
        var echo = 'Run P03';
        timeout(RS, echo);
    });
};

//do for loop test
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    p01().then(function (echo) {
        console.log(echo);
        return p02();
    }).then(function (echo) {
        console.log(echo);
        return p03();
    }).then(function (echo) {
        console.log(echo);
        console.log('Done!');
    });
};
```

when loop done, log show me that:

```
(3)Run P01
(3)Run P02
Run P03
Done!
Run P03
Done!
Run P03
Done!
```

I don't know what wrong happen, how do I fix that to get like this:

```
Run P01
Run P02
Run P03
Done!
Run P01
Run P02
Run P03
Done!
Run P01
Run P02
Run P03
Done!
```

thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, each iteration in your `for` loop is running *synchronously*, one after another. The `Promise` chain gets initialized, but you aren't waiting for it to resolve before going on to the next iteration (and initializing another `Promise` chain).

Either put the loop in an `async` function and `await` the `Promise` chain on each iteration (so that the next iteration doesn't start until the current iteration's has completely finished):

```js
//timeout
timeout = function(fn, pkg) {
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
    fn(pkg);
    clearTimeout(t);
  }, 1000);
};
//Promise function
p01 = function(check) {
  return new Promise(function(RS, RJ) {
    var echo = 'Run P01';
    timeout(RS, echo);
  });
};
p02 = function(check) {
  return new Promise(function(RS, RJ) {
    var echo = 'Run P02';
    timeout(RS, echo);
  });
};
p03 = function(check) {
  return new Promise(function(RS, RJ) {
    var echo = 'Run P03';
    timeout(RS, echo);
  });
};

//do for loop test

(async () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    await p01().then(function(echo) {
      console.log(echo);
      return p02();
    }).then(function(echo) {
      console.log(echo);
      return p03();
    }).then(function(echo) {
      console.log(echo);
      console.log('Done!');
    });
  }
})();
```

Or have an outer Promise that you reassign and call `.then` on each time:

```js
//timeout
timeout = function (fn, pkg) {
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        fn(pkg);
        clearTimeout(t);
    }, 1000);
};
//Promise function
p01 = function (check) {
    return new Promise(function (RS, RJ) {
        var echo = 'Run P01';
        timeout(RS, echo);
    });
};
p02 = function (check) {
    return new Promise(function (RS, RJ) {
        var echo = 'Run P02';
        timeout(RS, echo);
    });
};
p03 = function (check) {
    return new Promise(function (RS, RJ) {
        var echo = 'Run P03';
        timeout(RS, echo);
    });
};

//do for loop test
let prom = Promise.resolve();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    prom = prom.then(p01).then(function (echo) {
        console.log(echo);
        return p02();
    }).then(function (echo) {
        console.log(echo);
        return p03();
    }).then(function (echo) {
        console.log(echo);
        console.log('Done!');
    });
};
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much for your help, again